# Regular expression - How to eliminate certain pattern in python

Tags: python, regex

I have some articles containing match scores like 13-9, 34-12, 22-10 which I want to extract using a regular expression to find the pattern in Python. `re.compile(r'[0-9]+-[0-9]')`works but how can I modify to eliminate 1999-06, 2020-01? I tried `re.compile(r'[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]')`but those year values return as 99-06 which is also invalid in my case.

Comment: Try `re.compile(r'(?<![0-9]{2})[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match for exact number of digits required with look behind assertions, not to slice log numbers, like below

```regex
(?<!\d)\d{2}-\d{1,2}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RNzzEQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid matching in the middle of a number with

```py
r'(?<!\d)[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]'
```

The negative lookbehind prohibits matching immediately after another digit.

Perhaps also add

```py
(?!\d)
```

at the end to impose a similar restriction at the end of the match.